# JEST test suite fails with TypeError: environment.setup is not a function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to add tests to my app and the test fails with the following error:

> Test suite failed to run
>
> ```
> TypeError: environment.setup is not a function
>
>   at node_modules/jest-runner/build/run_test.js:71:23
> ```

Below are my config files used in a  project:

> .babelrc
>
> ```
> {
>     "presets": [
>         "env",
>         "react"
>     ],
>     "plugins": [
>         "transform-class-properties",
>         "transform-object-rest-spread"
>     ],
>     "env": {
>         "test": {
>             "presets": [
>                 "env",
>                 "react"
>             ],
>             "plugins": [
>                 "transform-class-properties",
>                 "transform-object-rest-spread"
>             ]
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> jest.config.json
>
> ```
> {
>     "transform": {
>         "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
>     },
>     "setupFiles": [
>         "raf/polyfill",
>         "<rootDir>/src/tests/setupTests.js"
>     ],
>     "snapshotSerializers": [
>         "enzyme-to-json/serializer"
>     ]
> }
> ```
>
> package.json
>
> ```
> {
>   "scripts": {
>     "build:prod": "webpack -p --env production",
>     "build:dev": "webpack --env development",
>     "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server",
>     "test": "jest --config=jest.config.json"
>   },
>   "author": "Lukasz 'Severiaan' Grela",
>   "dependencies": {
>     "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
>     "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
>     "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
>     "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
>     "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
>     "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
>     "css-loader": "^0.28.9",
>     "enzyme": "^3.3.0",
>     "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.1.1",
>     "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.1",
>     "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "3.0.2",
>     "jest": "^22.3.0",
>     "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
>     "raf": "^3.4.0",
>     "react": "^16.2.0",
>     "react-dom": "^16.2.0",
>     "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
>     "react-responsive": "^4.0.3",
>     "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
>     "react-scripts": "1.0.17",
>     "redux": "^3.7.2",
>     "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
>     "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
>     "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
>     "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
>     "webpack": "^3.11.0",
>     "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
>   },
>   "devDependencies": {
>     "babel-jest": "^22.2.2"
>   }
> }
> ```

What could be the problem, did anyone encounter similar problem? Thanks for any hints:)

Comment: related to https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/5119 ?

Comment: @Hamms I've tried to move my project from create-react-app to webpack, could it be the side effect?

Comment: afraid I don't know anything about create-react-app

Comment: It was the left over from the transition, the `react-scripts` in the `package.json`, I've removed it, run `yarn` and then start the test and now it works. Thanks. I've found the problem using command from your link: `npm ls jest-environment-node`.

Answer (score 2):

Add

`"jest": {
    "testEnvironment": "node"
  }`

to your package.json file,it would be like this:

```
    .
    .
    .
    "redux-promise": "^0.5.3",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.20.2",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack": "^3.11.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^2.11.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-jest": "^22.2.2"
      },
      "jest": {
        "testEnvironment": "node"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Will only work if you `eject`  the default setup. You can do so by running `npm run eject `

Comment: @June thats true if you use default react-scripts test as test command in package.json. but here we use JEST as test command and it works fine.